# Minimum and Maximum value for UIAccelerationValue?

Tags: ios, numbers, max, minimum

Please pardon me if this has been asked before but I am trying to limit a UIAccelerationValue to between 2 numbers, pretty much making a minimum value and a maximum value.

So, right now I am not sure how or if I should use the MAX or MIN functions.

To put it simple I don't want my variable 'accelerationValue' to be below -10 or 10.

How would I achieve this using MIN or MAX functions and again please pardon me if this asked been asked before or if it is a stupid question.

Thanks!

Comment: `accelerationValue = accelerationValue < -10 ? -10 : (accelerationValue > 10 ? 10 : accelerationValue);`

Comment: I see, but can I do not do this using MIN, MAX functions? I must use technically if checks to do this?

Comment: Also isn't it possible to use abs() to combine those 2 checks into one and then set the value back to their respective signs? That would make it very readable and concise! :P